# Error when declaring variable in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a private Node class that keeps track of a key, value, and the next Node, linking all the Nodes together.

However, when I try to declare the numItems, and the head of the list I get an error stating that they were never declared.

```
    typedef struct NodeObj{
       char* key;
       char* val;
       struct NodeObj* next; 
    } NodeObj;
    typedef NodeObj* Node;

    Node newNode(char* x, char* y){
     //makes a Node N and returns N
     // x->key, y->val next->NULL
    }

    //the main class
    typedef struct ListObj{
        Node head;
        int numItems;
    } ListObj;

    List newList(void){
       List L = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));
       assert(L!=NULL);
       L->Head = NULL;
       L->numItems = 0;
       return L;
    }
    //whenever I try to reference Head or numItems I get errors stating 
    //that they haven't been declared?
```

the errors I get are

```
 List.c: In function'find':
 List.c:59:11: error: 'head' undeclared(first use in this function)
    Node N = head

 List.c:60: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

The same error gets repeated whenever I reference numItems or Head, and i use -std=c99 to compile

Comment: would you include the compiler error pls

Comment: `private Node class`...in `C`...which standard, please?

Comment: What is `List`? `head` != `Head`

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing which might go wrong here.

1. List L = malloc( sizeof(ListObj) ); // this should be a pointer type
   => List* L = ....
2. List L and ListObj are different types so even writing
   List* L = malloc( sizeof( ListObj ) ) will not have the desired effet

Answer (score 0):

```
//the main class
typedef struct ListObj{
    Node head;
    int numItems;
} ListObj;
typedef ListObj* List;    ////add this line, it'll work fine
List newList(void){
   List L = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));
   assert(L!=NULL);
   L->Head = NULL;
   L->numItems = 0;
   return L;
}
```

Comment: NOOOOOOO...it will be List L = malloc(sizeof(ListObj)); only, since it will become ListObj* L = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));, no?...which is pointer itself.

Comment: yes you are right - missed that - deletetd the comment